# Is there a way to reference a newly created worksheet from another workbook, with a vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, vlookup, worksheet

I am Trying to simplify a VBA VLook up, which basically looks up data from another workbook, into a tab which gets crated daily each morning.

- The File name which the V-Look up references is called Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm
- Where the formula reads RC133, the starting cell being used is "EH2"

Currently, my formula reads;

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1=VLOOKUP(RC[133],'[Unavista UTI Lookup December2019.xlsm]Dec 02'!C4:C7,4,0)
```

- I've hard coded the file name in cell "P19" and set it as "MyLookupFile"

However it's the sheet name which I am having an issue with. Each morning a new tab in the other file gets created with today's date in the format as "MMM D"

Does anyone know what is the most simple, easy to read formula, so that my VBA code can reference the name of the file in the lookup, along with "MyLookupfile" and with the latest worksheet created?

So in the end, the formula would look something along the lines of the below as an Example;

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("EH2"),[MyLookupFile & LatestCreatedTab], C4:C7, 4, 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try maybe something like `ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(EH2,[" & Range("MyLookupFile").VALUE & "]" & Format(Now, "MMM DD") & "!C4:C7,4,0)"`